# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 in a List<HashMap<String,String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this method that must insert in an `ArrayList` elements in this way:

```
0 Low 10
0 High 11
0 High 3
1 Low 54
```

For this, I use an `HashMap` for the last two elements in a row and then put this `HashMap` in an `ArrayList`. This is the code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String label[];
    JCheckBox casella=new JCheckBox();

    //System.out.println(data.get(0).get("name"));

    if(jList2.getModel().getSize()>0){ //Se sono state selezionate PAD
        for(int i=0; i<jPanel2.getComponentCount(); i++){ //Controlla se le PAD hanno i prode
            label=(casella.getText()).split(" ");
            if( (casella=(JCheckBox) jPanel2.getComponent(i)).isSelected() ){ //Si
                map.put(label[2], label[4]);
                data.add(1,map);
            }
            else{ //No
                map.put(label[2], label[4]);
                data.add(0,map);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data.size());
```

The trouble is that on the lines `map.put(label[2], label[4]);` I have this message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

I can not understand where am I wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the String array resulting from

```
label=(casella.getText()).split(" ");
```

doesn't have enough elements (less than 2 resp. 4), you get this exception.

You should find out how long this array is before using it.

Answer (score 1):

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

Means you don't have enough elements in your `Array` to extract it out.

In `Java`, `Array` index starts from `0`, so probably below code will work, Also you can extract `map.put(label[1], label[3]);` out as it's common in both `if and else` condition:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String label[];
        JCheckBox casella=new JCheckBox();

        //System.out.println(data.get(0).get("name"));

        if(jList2.getModel().getSize()>0){ //Se sono state selezionate PAD
            for(int i=0; i<jPanel2.getComponentCount(); i++){ //Controlla se le PAD hanno i prode
                label=(casella.getText()).split(" ");
                map.put(label[1], label[3]);
                if( (casella=(JCheckBox) jPanel2.getComponent(i)).isSelected() ){ //Si 
                    data.add(1,map);
                }
                else{ //No
                    data.add(0,map);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(data.size());
}}
```